# ESXI - Invalid configuration for device '5'

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, esxi

I am trying to create a new VM on ESXI 6.0 using a Windows Server 2012 R2 `.iso` file.

After selecting all VM options and when finalizing the creation, the process fails with the following **extremely** informative message:

> Failed - Invalid configuration for device '5'.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

My only concern is that ESXI by default does not offer the very **specific** option of selecting `Windows 2012 R2 Server` as OS (check attached image) - so I dont' know if this is causing the failure.

(I am selecting just `Windows Server 2012`, without the `R2` since it doesn't exist)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[**Device 5**](https://blogs.vmware.com/vapp/2009/11/virtual-hardware-in-ovf-part-1.html.) stands for IDE controller.

I managed to solve the similar issue by creating the VM without attached **HDD and SCSI controller** (WinServ 2016 in my case). Then you can try to attach a HDD and Controller lately.